# Anyone happen to know if with 21.04 AD integration, tighter integration with Certificate Services is being considered?

Tags: windows, ssl, certificates, active-directory, microsoft

As an admin in a mixed environment, the biggest bane of my existence it trying to issue internal certs. Right now the only option is using NDES/SCEP, but Microsoft apparently has no interest in supporting that since it can't support their CNG certificate providers, which means the only certificates I can issue to linux machines via NDES/SCEP is ones using older cryptography. Not to mention that setting that up in Windows still often results in crashing the Windows crypto Schannel module and all kinds of nastiness because managing it requires IE and older libraries etc...

Now that Ubuntu is adding some tighter integration with AD targeting SQL Sever and the like, certainly being able to automatically enroll the machine and programs like SQL Server for AD issued certificates has to be a consideration. I haven't been able to find any mention of anything to do with certificates around this.

Are there any threads, docs, or other information on this out there?

Comment: We can't answer questions about the intentions or plans of developers since we do not represent Ubuntu development.

Comment: @Nmath I suppose the title is not particularly pointed, and the body a little ranty; really I'm hoping for an answer to the concluding question of whether there's any threads, docs, or other mentions around this kind of thing; google searches have been pretty fruitless.